# Are these two molecules enantiomers or diastereomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image: Stereoisomers]

I had a long discussion with my professor about these two molecules, and we both agreed to do some of our own research and reconvene. These two molecules appear to be non-superimposable mirror images of one another, so they should be enantiomers. 
However, this conflicts with the "trick" commonly taught when teaching students about enantiomers and diastereomers:

> Invert *all* of the stereocenters in a molecule to get its enantiomer. If you invert some of the stereocenters in a molecule and leave the others untouched, you will make a diastereomer.

[image: Stereoisomers with stereochemical assignments]

These molecules each have 4 stereocenters, the two carbons with hydroxy groups and the two bridgehead carbons. Despite the fact that only the carbons with hydroxy groups are inverted from (R,R) to (S,S), and the two bridgehead carbons are left alone, it appears that the two molecules are in fact enantiomers.

If they are enantiomers, what is wrong with the trick described above? If they are in fact diastereomers, why?

Comment: You are looking at a 2D projection of the molecule. Turn the second one around in your head an you'll see that they all are inverted.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE! Are they mirror images or not? If so, they are enantiomers. There is nothing wrong with your "trick" except that inverting only one bridgehead will lead to a highly strained structure that will not exist.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I assigned absolute stereochemistry to show that only two of the four stereocenters are being inverted. They are not all being inverted.

Comment: @2400Knots your stereochemistry labels are wrong. The left compound is (1R,2S,3S,4S)-bicyclo[2.2.1]hept-5-ene-2,3-diol and the right compound is (1R,2R,3R,4S)-bicyclo[2.2.1]hept-5-ene-2,3-diol.

Comment: @user55119 Thank you! I am not sure if they are mirror images or not. The atoms all appear to be mirrored, but the stereochemical assignments of the bridgehead carbons are not. I am not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: Okay, next try: turn both molecules 90 degrees towards or against each other. Draw a line in the middle. All inverted.

Comment: Follow @Martin 's advice. R mirrors S.

Comment: I think I see it now. Thanks for your help. https://i.ibb.co/rxHyFyH/image.png